# resize view width based on counts of element in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to know is it possible to have dynamic width for view based on elements exist in a row ? In this below picture, I want to have different width for process button based on pictures beside it. The maximum number of pictures beside the process button is 4 and the minimum is 0.

[image]

Comment: have you tried Horizontal LinearLayout with weight?

Comment: it should be done with java code i think. In fact, user tries to add a picture to this row and after each adding , the size of process button should be decreased

Comment: create Horizontal LinearLayout and add proccess buton with weight 1. then from java code keep adding new views inside of layout and process button should be resized automaticly.

Comment: oppss, I'll try. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your this requirement, you can use LinearLayout's weight property, I am writing a representational code for understanding, take all the image views with width "wrap_content", take button with weight=1 and width=0dp, make images visible and hidden as per logic, Button will cover the rest space.

```
<Img1/
width="wrap_content"
visibility="visible"
>

<Img2/
width="wrap_content"
visibility="visible"
>

<Img3/
width="wrap_content"
visibility="visible"
>

<Img4/
width="wrap_content"
visibility="visible"
>

<Button
width = "0dp"
weight="1"
>
```